# Date conversion

Tags: c#, date, formatting

How to convert the date displayed 7/19/2010 12:00:00 AM to July/Sunday/2010???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you already have this as a DateTime? If so, it's easy:

```
string text = dt.ToString("MMMM'/'dddd'/'yyyy");
```

This will use the thread's current culture - you can use a specific culture or the invariant culture, e.g.

```
string text = dt.ToString("MMMM'/'dddd'/'yyyy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that the "/" has been escaped here, as otherwise it would use the culture's date separator symbol. Another option for escaping is to use a backslash, but then you need to either escape *that* or use a verbatim string literal (assuming C# due to your previous questions):

```
string text = dt.ToString(@"MMMM\/dddd\/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MMMM\/dddd\/yyyy");
```